# 2 processes but not related in nextflow pipeline

Tags: bash, awk, anaconda, nextflow

i have 2 processes but it is not related to the next one here:
FASTQC_check and FASTQC_1 this means I don't care about the input of FASTQC_1 but I want FASTQC_check to run after FASTQC_1 completes (i want to print the screen when everything done)!
what should I do? I tried the.out but it can solve my problem!

```
workflow {
  read_pairs_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs(params.reads)
  fastqc= FASTQC(read_pairs_ch)
  trimmomatic(read_pairs_ch)
  **FASTQC_1**(trimmomatic.out)
  **FASTQC_check**(FASTQC_1.out)
  if (FASTQC_check.out) {
    Channel
      .fromPath('/home/dungnguyen/genepanel/bin/data3.txt')  
      .splitText()
      .view { 
        println it 
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial thought was that you could use the [state dependency](https://nextflow-io.github.io/patterns/state-dependency) pattern for this, but I think you could just as easily pass down the sample names to the *FASTQC_check* process, for example:

```
process FASTQC_1 {

    tag { sample }

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(fastq)

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path "*_fastqc.{zip,html}"

    """
    fastqc -q "${fastq}"
    """
}

process FASTQC_check {

    tag { sample }

    input:
    val sample

    """
    # do something
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    read_pairs_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs(params.reads)

    FASTQC(read_pairs_ch)
    trimmomatic(read_pairs_ch)
    FASTQC_1(trimmomatic.out)

    FASTQC_1.out
        .map { sample, fastqc -> sample }
        .set { ready_ch }

    FASTQC_check(ready_ch)
}
```

If *FASTQC_check* should run after *all* instances of *FASTQC_1*, you could call [collect](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#collect) to produce a ready signal for example:

```
process FASTQC_check {

    input:
    val ready

    """
    # do something
    """
}

workflow {

    ...

    FASTQC_1.out
        .map { sample, fastqc -> sample }
        .collect()
        .set { ready_ch }

    FASTQC_check(ready_ch)
}
```