# How can I make sure Nextflow processes don't run simultaneously?

Tags: pipeline, bioinformatics, nextflow

I am running a Nextflow pipeline that basically sends a bunch of files through multiple tools and collects resulting CSVs; however, two of the tools I need cannot be run simultaneously (they use the same software under the hood, and we only have one license). The pipeline looks like this:

```
workflow MY_WORKFLOW {
    take:
    pdb_ch

    main:
    csv1_ch = TOOL1(pdb_ch)
    bundled_pdb_ch = pdb_ch.collate(20)
    csv2_ch = TOOL2(bundled_pdb_ch)
    csv3_ch = TOOL3(bundled_pdb_ch)
    out_ch = csv1_ch.mix(csv2_ch).mix(csv3_ch)

    emit:
    out_ch
}
```

The order in which they launch doesn't matter: I'm okay if TOOL1 processes the entire dataset and then TOOL3 starts, or if they run in alternating order, or whatever. What matters is that at any point in time there should be either one of these two running or neither, but never both.

Using `maxForks` directive allows making sure only only one instance *of a given process* is running, but is there a way to generate some more general lock/semaphore that could be shared between different processes?

Comment: Adding as a comment because not sure it's what you need, but `nextflow run` has a "-qs" (queue size) option so you can limit how many processes at all run at one time. Could set this to 1 for full serial execution.

Comment: This won't work because I want *these particular processes* to only run one at a time, but also want others to be paralellized.

Comment: you likely want the `maxForks` process directive https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#maxforks 
However since you have multiple processes, you may need to instead combine them into something like a single process with a conditional that alternates different `script` blocks
https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#conditional-scripts
so you would have a single process `DO_THING` with a flag that changes which `script` gets used, and set that process to `maxForks` of 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by adapting the answer found in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76801059/2-processes-but-not-related-in-nextflow-pipeline). The trick is to create a process that accepts TOOL1 output and emits some value, like this:

```
process BLOCK {
    input:
    path csv_files

    output:
    val ready
    // Does nothing except return a value
    
    exec:
    ready = 1
}
```

Then this process needs to be inserted into the pipeline by feeding it `TOOL3` results and making its outputs an additional input for TOOL1:

```
bundled_pdb_ch = pdb_ch.collate(20)
csv2_ch = TOOL2(bundled_pdb_ch)
csv3_ch = TOOL3(bundled_pdb_ch)
semaphore_ch = BLOCK(csv3_ch.collect())
csv1_ch = TOOL1(pdb_ch, semaphore_ch)
out_ch = csv1_ch.mix(csv2_ch).mix(csv3_ch)
```

`BLOCK` is only launched when `csv_ch3` can be collected (*ie* all instances of TOOL3 have finished), and `TOOL1` will not run without a value from `semaphore_ch`. This value is actually ignored by `TOOL1` body, but it is still necessary for process to launch. And since it's a value channel, it can be read as many times as necessary without being exhausted.

Technically, intermediate process is not necessary because I could just pass `csv3_ch.collect()` to a second channel of `TOOL1`. However, it prevents `TOOL1` work directories from being littered with `TOOL3` outputs